# Не работает новое, чистое Vue приложение

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Пожалуйста помоги, у меня руки опускаются, обычно я всегда сам находил решения всех ошибок и проблем, но тут я в загнал себя в тупик. Пробовал на разных компьютерах, в разных браузерах, отключал Adblock и прочие блокировщики рекламы, переустанавливал Node js, CLI.
Я создал новое Vue приложение через vue create, АБСОЛЮТНО ничего не изменял в файлах, запускаю через npm run dev, перехожу по ссылке localhost и ничего не отображается, в консоли мне выводит это -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
at eval (stripAnsi.js?7085:18:1)
at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/stripAnsi.js (chunk-vendors.js:325:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:124:33)
at fn (app.js:357:21)
at eval (index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.0.105&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true:7:77)
at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.0.105&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true (chunk-vendors.js:172:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:124:33)
at app.js:1243:83
at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:170:23)
at app.js:1246:53
```

При переходе по ссылке на место ошибки мне выдаёт это:

```js
try {
    var execOptions = { id: moduleId, module: module, factory: __webpack_modules__[moduleId], require: __webpack_require__ };
    __webpack_require__.i.forEach(function(handler) { handler(execOptions); });
    module = execOptions.module;
    execOptions.factory.call(module.exports, module, module.exports, execOptions.require);
 } catch(e) {
    module.error = e;
    throw e;
 }
```

В интернете ничего не смог найти толкового, у всех ошибки с их готовыми проектами, а у меня девственно чистый, новый проект и даже стандартный наполнитель не отображает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `npm run build` делали?) p.s. рекомендую https://vitejs.dev/

Comment: Нет, не делал. Написал, всё заработало... Почему об этом в нигде не было сказано, во всех гайдах и курсах на ютубе все начинают с команды npm run serve и у них всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: про vitejs знаю, и мне он нравится больше, там без проблем работает всё с первого раза. Препод в универе говорит в Vue CLI делать, поэтому делаю через него)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему написав `npm run build`, перед тем как написать `npm run serve`